# fetching data using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i have player table has name and profileId

profile table has numberOfKills ,rankId and power

rank table has rankName

i want to get all players data from above orderd by rank top 100
using this code

```
let players: any = await Player.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'name',
    'profile.numberOfKills',
    'profilepower',
    'profile.rankId',
  ],
  include: [
    {
      model: Profile,
      include: [
        {
          model: Level,
          attributes: ['name'],
          as: 'rank',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  order: ['profile.numberOfKills', 'DESC'],
  limit: 100,
});
```

"message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')"

what to do
using sequelize and not literal query

Comment: It's not clear when the error message is raised. it looks like you try to access "type" field from undefined.

Comment: i guess it is raised in the order statement cz i tried to remove it and i got data correctly but not ordered but need them to be ordered !

Answer (score 0):

The `order` [should be an array](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#ordering) that contains either *another array* per field you want to sort on or functions like `sequelize.random()`, `sequelize.col('name')`, etc.

Change:

```
order: ['profile.numberOfKills', 'DESC'],
```

to:

```
order: [
  ['profile.numberOfKills', 'DESC'],
],
```

Comment: ok tnx for the like .. it worked using     order: [[{ model: Profile , as : "profile" }, 'numberOfKills', "DESC"]] ... but this way its getting me all profile data (numOfKills , power , rankId and other data) how to get these 3 data ONLY

Comment: Isn't that just adding `attributes: ['power', 'rankId', etc...]` to the `include: [{ model: Profile }]` object?

Comment: Well yes but i posted another question may u plz help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `literal` and it works!

```
order: [
  [sequelize.literal('`profile.numberOfKills`'), 'DESC']
]
```